Intersection of symmetry elements in space groups
How can I estabilish a priori if two symmetry elements can intersect or not in a space groups?
If I understand correctly, when the group is symmorphic I don't have problems: derive the general positions and then move the origin if it's the case.
But when the group is non-symmorphic looking at diagrams I have to choose the correct relative positions of symmetry elements because they don't intersect at the point I can choose as an origin.
For example, here in P4nc group:
https://images.app.goo.gl/SHgWXBQkYP3764HR7
the two glide-planes don't intersect the 4 axis. Why? How can I fix the distance between the intersection of the two planes and the 4 axis starting from the Hermann-Mauguin symbol?

if you are referring to glide planes with the graphical symbol ( .._ ), they actually intersect in the position where the 4-fold axis is found. Look at the 4-fold axis at the center of the plane of projection. It is symmetrically equivalent to the other 4-fold axis found at the edge (it is the position 2a).
